# GetDC, ReleaseDC, CS_OWNDC with OpenGL and Gdi+

Tags: winapi, opengl, gdi+

Reading about GetDC/ReleaseDC I should it appears always do the latter, and that CS_OWNDC on a window is considered evil:

```
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003
```

Looking through my code I see I'm holding onto a DC retrieved from GetDC, which I've sent into wglCreateContextAttribARB.  I'm presuming the context is created on that DC so it would be bad manners to subsequently release it from under the driver.   Is my assumption correct?  At the moment I'm calling ReleaseDC when I destroy my other OpenGL resources.

Additionally, elsewhere in my libraries I'm calling GetDC to instantiate a GDI+ Graphics object, then releasing it again when I've finished drawing.  I'm thinking it would be nice to persist the DC and Graphics object between draw calls for performance reasons, only recreating it on WM_DISPLAYCHANGE etc.

So, is there a definitive guide to best practice in this area?  The way I diligently release the GDI+ DC but persist the OpenGL DC seems somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL and GDI+ behave differently.

In OpenGL you need a context, which is *attached* with a `DC`. This means that the `DC` **must** exist while the context exists. Thus, you do need `CS_OWNDC` style for the window where OpenGL draws.

Call `ReleaseDC` after you have deleted the context.

GDI+ is used in MS Windows like any common `DC`: retrieve a DC, draw to it, release that DC. In this scenary the use of `CS_OWNDC` can be evil, as pointed out in the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003) you posted.

The way MS GDI+ uses the graphics hardware (i.e. creating a context or whatever) is irrelevant for you.

---

**EDIT** due to Chris Becke's comment:

**The CS_OWNDC usage is not required**

Quoting https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx:

> The hdc parameter must refer to a drawing surface supported by OpenGL.
>   It need not be the same hdc that was passed to wglCreateContext when
>   hglrc was created, but it must be on the same device and have the same
>   pixel format.

**The CS_OWNDC usage is recommended.**

In the old days of Windows 9x acquiring and releasing a device context was expensive and slow. Having a *fixed dc* was much more efficent. Using the `CS_OWNDC` flag at window registration was the way to have a *fixed dc*.

The `CS_OWNDC` usage provides a *private device context* (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#class_styles).

Quoting from MS docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162872(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Although a private device context is convenient to use, it is
>   memory-intensive in terms of system resources, requiring 800 or more
>   bytes to store. Private device contexts are recommended when
>   performance considerations outweigh storage costs.

You must be aware that you must avoid `ReleaseDC` with a private device context:

> An application can retrieve a handle to the private device context by
>   using the GetDC function any time after the window is created. The
>   application must retrieve the handle only once. Thereafter, it can
>   keep and use the handle any number of times. Because a private device
>   context is not part of the display device context cache, an
>   application need never release the device context by using the
>   ReleaseDC function.

In the common scenary where you draw to an unique window by retriving a `DC`, setting the curent context, drawing, swapping buffers and releasing the `DC` the usage of CS_OWNDC instead of GetDC&ReleaseDC is natural.

It can be also the case where `wglGetCurrentDC()` is used (e.g. by an extern library) regarless of  your GetDC/ReleaseDC code. Normally no issues will happen. But if the current gl-context is NULL (as you would do right after ReleaseDC) then `wglGetCurrentDC()` will fail.

**Code without CS_OWNDC**

 used in two windows **with the same pixel format** would look like this:

```
myGLContext = wglCreateContext(...)

//Draw to window A
HDC hdcA = GetDC(hWndA)
wglMakeCurrent(hdcA, myGLContext)
... render...
SwapBuffers(hdcA)
ReleaseDC(hWndA, hdcA)

//Draw to window B
HDC hdcB = GetDC(hWndB)
wglMakeCurrent(hdcB, myGLContext)
... render...
SwapBuffers(hdcB)
ReleaseDC(hWndA, hdcA)

wglMakeCurrent(hdcB, NULL)
```

Comment: OK, that sounds to me like a good general rule to live by.  CS_OWNDC is bad *in the context of GDI, GDI+*.  It's not blanket bad in all circumstances.

Comment: This is rubbish. The pixel format is set on the *window*, and all window DCs retrieved for the window will work with the gl context. Even OpenGL does not require the use of CS_OWNDC.

Comment: @ChrisBecke But in the official Khronos wiki (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) we can read that CS_OWNDC flag should be used: "When you create your HWND, you need to make sure that it has the CS_OWNDC set for its style."

Comment: Yes - I Read that too. But thats a wiki page of dubious quality. I can't find any corroboration of that bizarre claim in any of the official standards docs. And it does conflict implicitly with the MSDN documentation on the wgl* and SetPixelFormat* functions which - to me at least - are worded in a way that imply that any HDC that represents the window is equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisBecke MSDN says that: "The GetDC function retrieves a common, class, or private DC depending on the class style of the specified window." So when CS_OWNDC flag is not specified, we get the common, class DC. So for such DC, pixel format can only be set once. If we create a "fake" window to retrieve extensions and functions for better OpenGL context creation, and if we want to create another window with another context, we cannot choose other pixel format (for example one that supports multisampling). For this we need a DC associated with a given window, so CS_OWNDC flag is required.

Comment: GetDC takes an HWND anyway, so you always get A DC that represents 'a given window' that has had the pixel format set.

Comment: @ChrisBecke But if CS_OWNDC flag is not specified, then GetDC() can return a common, class context. So (as I understand) the same DC will be returned for all windows created from a given class. And if so, different pixel formats cannot be used for all those windows (SetPixelFormat() with different pixel format IDs won't work, because the same DC will be provided to this function).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369049(v=vs.85).aspx - This page clearly shows that the pixel format is set on the window. Its also points out the class style restrictions a window should have to be used with OpenGL, and omits any requirement on CS_OWNDC. If CS_OWNDC was a real requirement, it would definitely be mentioned on this page.

Comment: @ChrisBecke No, this page states: "The SetPixelFormat function sets the pixel format of the specified **device context** [...] **If** hdc references a window, calling the SetPixelFormat function **also** changes the pixel format of the window." So no, it sets a pixel format for a given device context. If there is a common, class DC, it cannot be associated with a window. Or, in other words - each window is associated with (the same) DC, but given DC is associated with multiple windows. As for OpenGL - if the same pixel format is used for all windows, then CS_OWNDC is indeed not required.

Comment: Looks like a typo in your sample code snippet: `SwapBuffers(hdcB)
ReleaseDC(hWndA, hdcA)`. Shouldn't it be `ReleaseDC(hWndB, hdcB)`? Btw. as such typos happen in (my) real code as well, I often use extra block scopes to limit the life-time of variables. Thus, I get a compiler error instead of strange run-time effects (where you could stare on the code for hours without noticing the typo). ;-)

Comment: This is an old thread but the assumption about CS_OWNDC and CS_CLASSDC here seems wrong.

- If you DON'T specify any on the window, then GetDC will give you a temporary DC, that you should release after painting.
- By specifying CS_OWNDC, a single DC will get created for that window, which will persist and you shouldn't release yourself.
- By specifying CS_CLASSDC, a DC is shared among ALL windows made from that window class.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060601-06/?p=31003
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060602-00/?p=30993