# Unable to get my first Windows opengl window up and running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

I'm trying to start an application which will run on windows 10 and us OpenGL.  I'm able to get a window on screen, however I can't get a color to show up within the window after initializing OpenGL. I'm trying not to use third party libraries like GLFW.

My current code is as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <cassert>

#define local_persist static
#define local_func static
#define global_variable static

namespace Win64
{
    local_func void
    ProcessPendingMessages()
    {
        MSG Message;
        while(GetMessageA(&Message, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            switch(Message.message)
            {
                case WM_QUIT:
                {
                } break;

                case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                case WM_SYSKEYUP:
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                case WM_KEYUP:
                {
                    uint32 VKCode = (uint32)Message.wParam;

                    if(VKCode == 'W')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == 'A')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == 'S')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == 'D')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == 'Q')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == 'E')
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_UP)
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_LEFT)
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_DOWN)
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_RIGHT)
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_ESCAPE)
                    {
                    }
                    else if(VKCode == VK_SPACE)
                    {
                    }
                }

                default:
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&Message);
                    DispatchMessageA(&Message);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    LRESULT CALLBACK
    ProgramWindowCallback(HWND WindowHandle, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        LRESULT Result{0};

        switch(Message)
        {
            case WM_SIZE:
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_SIZE\n");
            }break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_DESTROY\n");
            }break;

            case WM_CLOSE:
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_CLOSE\n");
            }break;

            case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
            {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVATEAPP\n");
            }break;

            case WM_PAINT:
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
                RECT ClientRect;
                GetClientRect(WindowHandle, &ClientRect);

                HDC DeviceContext = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &Paint);

                LONG Width = ClientRect.right - ClientRect.left;
                LONG Height = ClientRect.bottom - ClientRect.top;

                glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
                glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                SwapBuffers(DeviceContext);

                EndPaint(WindowHandle, &Paint);
            }break;

            default:
            {
                Result = DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, wParam, lParam);
            }break;
        }

        return Result;
    };
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE CurrentProgramInstance, HINSTANCE PrevInstance, LPSTR CommandLine, int ShowCode)
{
    WNDCLASS WindowProperties{};

    //TODO: Check if OWNDC/HREDRAW/VEDRAW matter
    WindowProperties.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    WindowProperties.lpfnWndProc = Win64::ProgramWindowCallback;
    WindowProperties.hInstance = CurrentProgramInstance;
    WindowProperties.lpszClassName = "MemoWindowClass";

    if(RegisterClass(&WindowProperties))
    {
        HWND Window = CreateWindowEx(0, WindowProperties.lpszClassName, "Memo", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, 
                                     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, CurrentProgramInstance, 0);

        if(Window)
        {
            HDC WindowDeviceContext = GetDC(Window);

            { //Init OpenGL
                HGLRC OpenGLRenderingContext = wglCreateContext(WindowDeviceContext);

                PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR DesiredPixelFormat{};
                DesiredPixelFormat.nSize = sizeof(DesiredPixelFormat);
                DesiredPixelFormat.nVersion = 1;
                DesiredPixelFormat.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
                DesiredPixelFormat.dwFlags = PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
                DesiredPixelFormat.cColorBits = 32;
                DesiredPixelFormat.cAlphaBits = 8;
                DesiredPixelFormat.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

                int SuggestedPixelFormatIndex = ChoosePixelFormat(WindowDeviceContext, &DesiredPixelFormat);
                PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR SuggestedPixelFormat{};
                DescribePixelFormat(WindowDeviceContext, SuggestedPixelFormatIndex, sizeof(SuggestedPixelFormat), &SuggestedPixelFormat);

                if (SetPixelFormat(WindowDeviceContext, SuggestedPixelFormatIndex, &SuggestedPixelFormat))
                {
                    if (wglMakeCurrent(WindowDeviceContext, OpenGLRenderingContext))
                    {
                        //Success!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log error
                        assert(1 == 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Log error
                    assert(1 == 0);
                }
            }

            Win64::ProcessPendingMessages();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting glClear() to clear to the color I set in glClearColor(). However this is not happening. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your question? Can we see a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line calling `wglCreateContext()` just before `wglMakeCurrent`, and after setting the pixel format (the `SetPixelFormat()` call).

```
if (SetPixelFormat(WindowDeviceContext, SuggestedPixelFormatIndex, &SuggestedPixelFormat))
{
    HGLRC OpenGLRenderingContext = wglCreateContext(WindowDeviceContext);
    if (wglMakeCurrent(WindowDeviceContext, OpenGLRenderingContext))
    //...
```

[Creating a Rendering Context and Making It Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd318297(v=vs.85).aspx).

[OpenGL Win32 Tutorial Sample Code](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/win32_tutorial/)

Comment: Awesome. This was the issue. Thank you for the references as well.

Comment: @Jason, and don't forget the clean-up of the contexts

Comment: Okay yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue, but there is a horrible anti pattern in many OpenGL samples that create a window class using CS_OWNDC, and then assume its safe to call wglMakeCurrent once on program startup and never again.

It is far, FAR, safer to omit the CS_OWNDC style from the window class, and simply wrap all the entry points to your OpenGl calls with wglMakeCurrent to setup, and cleanup.

The pattern is, you want to do something with OpenGL so you call GetDC/BeginPaint as appropriate to get a window DC, then you call wglMakeCurrent passing the dc and gl rc handle, do your OpenGL calls, and then just before you call ReleaseDC / EndPaint, you call wglMakeCurrent again passing NULL,NULL.

Follow this basic advice and you can safely create multiple open gl window instances on a single thread, and you don't have to worry some 3rd party code might create, and temporarily make current, its own GL context.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663815/getdc-releasedc-cs-owndc-with-opengl-and-gdi) about CS_OWNDC

Comment: That answer is false. There is no hard association between a gl context and a window DC. Otherwise it would not be necessary to pass both to wglMakeCurrent. The pixel format is associated with the window the dc represents and all DCs obtained for that window can be used by OpenGL. This bizarre piece of 'common knowledge' has no basis in the Windows OpenGL documentation.